# How to pass a View to my ViewModel so an I*Service can use that View to do something

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction is a very nice plugin for showing cross platform Alerts!

But for this question, can we assume it can not use a UIAlertView (or some other top level MessageBox type call on other platforms) but needs to show a Message within a given subsection of the screen (i.e. on IPhone you would need to supply a UIView to the plugin which it will use to show the message within).

So, how would you set this up so the ViewModel knows what View to use as its display container?

As a specific example, if I wanted an Error Service, as so -

```
public interface IErrorPFService
{
    void Show();
    void Hide();
    void SetErrors(List<Error> errors);
}
```

and I create a platform specific implementation for it.

If I inject this into my ViewModel so it can control Error Show/Hide/Set how do I tell it the UIView (or equivalent) that I want my Errors to show within?

Can I just expose the IErrorPFService field as a public property and do -

```
MyViewModel.ErrorPFService = new ErrorPFService(View);
```

in my ViewDidLoad ...

Or is this coupled incorrectly vs Mvvm Practice?

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the ViewModel to subscribe **itself** to the ErrorService.

When receiving a message it would expose it in a collection(?) and the View would bind to that collection.

This way the View is unknown to the service and the ViewModel has the chance to influence the View contrary to your solution.

Comment: Thanks for comment Erno, considering next steps above.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you could give an example for the scenario you are describing.

Sometimes, the way you visually want to display something might not be the best way, so if it's possible for you, you might find a different and simpler way, which spares you from having to find a solution regarding what you are describing.

Generally, I always do the best I can to avoid the idea of having to actually pass a 'view' or an abstraction of it, from the view-model to view. Also, cross-platform wise, things can work very different in terms of UI interaction. You can find yourself in a situation when things are complicated just because UI works differently than what you expected.

But let's try find another perspective:

At any given point, the view knows what data \ feature it's displaying. So when you are calling from the view-model an user interaction action (by a service, property change, event, etc) the view should 'expect' it.

For example, the platform specific user interaction implementation is able to get the currently displayed top-view and interact it in a platform specific manner or based a relationship. In your example, the message-box can be displayed in a specific sub-view of the top level view.

In advanced scenarios, I guess you could try to create a cross-platform approach for this, but you should try to put in balance all the abstraction you want to create just for that. Think about doing this as a plan ... Z. If possible. Again, giving an example might help.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how to do this by putting some Properties on a ViewModel, like ErrorsList, ShowErrors, HideErrors and then setting them in the VM and reacting to them in the UI (I can then go and put them in the BaseViewModel if most screens use them ...), but I just wanted to understand a way to explicitly say that a VM supports the display of error information (hence the IErrorPFService) and then I want to ensure that the View is then able to process these Errors according to platform.    It felt like a plugin would be the eventual result like UserInteraction after resolved view issue!

Comment: I will go away and pursue some code / clarify the question as does not look like an obvious response .. its in the same area as displaying Dialogs in MVVM and there is a lot of literature about that and how to decouple things.

Comment: the example names you are giving like 'ShowsErrors' 'HideError' doesn't smell right to me for view-model. I'm trying to ask again if you have an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, will look at the KISS approach you describe and get back with more info.